# Syntax error when using \num inside \SI

Tags: siunitx

I'm using the siunitx, i.e. in the preamble of my document I'm including `\usepackage{siunitx}`.

If I write in my document `$\num{1234}$` it works very well, but if I try to use `$\SI{\num{1234}}{s}$` I'm getting a syntax error (invalid token).

Why and how can I prevent this?

Comment: \SI{1234}{s}$ -- `\num` is meant for numbers only -- the first argument of `\SI` is designed to take the unit value

Comment: You dont need to put `\num` inside `\SI`. Simply write `\SI{1234}{\second}`. You don't need `$`-sign aroubd it either. Use the `\sisetup{detect-all}`if you wish.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: MIght as well write up an answer to get this closed.  I thought you can use `\SI[parse-numbers=false]`, but then this seems to apply this option to the `\num` macro as well so that doesn't work. Related Question: [Use \num macro with \SI[parse-numbers=false](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321731/use-num-macro-with-siparse-numbers-false).

Comment: @PeterGrill: Well, I could add an answer, but actually, I think, Joseph should do so... I will add one, Joseph can still provide another (better) one ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use `\SI{1234}{\second}` if a unit and the value should be displayed together. Just use `\num` for the value only and `\si{\second}` for the unit only.

A combination of `\SI{\num....}{}` is not useful (and apparently wrong)

Comment: Well, you do need to use `\num` within an `\SI` macro if there is a `\frac`in the first parameter of `\SI` as per the linked question [Use \num macro with \SI\[parse-numbers=false\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321731/use-num-macro-with-siparse-numbers-false).