# Use \num macro with \SI[parse-numbers=false]

Tags: spacing, siunitx

It seems that when I apply the `[parse-numbers=false]` option to `\SI`, this *also* applies this option to the `\num` macro if it is *in the number parameter* of `\SI`.  I realize that there is usually no need for this, but it is needed when the "number" portion of the `\SI` macro has other content in it, for instance a `\frac` (last example in MWE).

This is probably on purpose, but I feel that it should not be this way. I think of the `\num` macro separately from the `\SI` macro. In my opinion, an option should *only* apply to a macro that is given to.

### Question:

Is there a way I can setup the `\siunitx` macros so that `\num` does *not* inherit the options applied to `\SI`?

[image]

---

### Notes:

Possible workaround include

- It seems that if I use `\num[parse-numbers=true]`, then things work, but I would prefer not to have to do that.
- Another option is to use `$\frac{1}{\num{100000}}\,\si{\meter}$`, but again I would prefer to use `\SI[parse-numbers=false]` macro for consistency instead of manual spacing.

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\textbf{OK}

Outside of \verb|\SI|: \num{100000}
 
In a \verb|\frac|: $\frac{1}{\num{100000}}$

Inside of \verb|\SI| without \verb|\num|: \SI{100000}{\meter} 

\medskip
\textbf{Problem}

Inside of \verb|\SI[parse-numbers=false]| with \verb|\num|: 
\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\color{red}\num{100000}}{\meter}
$\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\color{red}\frac{1}{\num{100000}}}{\meter}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Short of 'no', what would be an answer here?

Comment: @JosephWright: That would be fine, but I just don't see why `\num` should inherit the options, nor a case where `\num[parse-numbers=true]` would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quick-and-dirty solution redefines `\num` in terms of the original definition from `siunitx.sty` to always include `parse-numbers=true`.  To override this, you can still pass `parse-numbers=false` to the new `\num`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\RenewDocumentCommand \num { o m } {
  \leavevmode
  \group_begin:
    \bool_set_false:N \l__siunitx_font_set_bool
    \IfNoValueTF {#1} % <- changed
      { \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {parse-numbers=true} } % <- changed
      { \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {parse-numbers=true,#1} } % <- changed
    \__siunitx_number_output:n {#2}
  \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\textbf{OK}

Outside of \verb|\SI|: \num{100000}

In a \verb|\frac|: $\frac{1}{\num{100000}}$

Inside of \verb|\SI| without \verb|\num|: \SI{100000}{\meter} 

\medskip
\textbf{Problem}

Inside of \verb|\SI[parse-numbers=false]| with \verb|\num|: 
\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\color{red}\num{100000}}{\meter}
$\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\color{red}\frac{1}{\num{100000}}}{\meter}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great. Any advantage of this solution compared to using `\LetLtxMacro\OldNum\num` and `\RenewDocumentCommand{\num}{O{} m}{\OldNum[parse-numbers=true,#1]{#2}}`?

Comment: @PeterGrill This is a very bad idea.  See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285551) of mine.

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't quite understand Joseph's answer, but will follow the advice given and use your code.

Comment: Why not just `\SI[quotient-mode = fraction, number-color = red]{1/10000}{\metre}`?